# In Futurama, are there jungles on Earth?

Tags: futurama

In the Futurama episode "Mars University" the Professor implies that there are no jungles on Earth.

> Fry: Wow! The jungles on Mars look just like the jungles on Earth!
>
> Professor: Jungles? On Earth? (wheezing, old man laughter)

But, in the episode "Debate 3012", while Fry, Leela, and Bender are going to Chris Traver's birthplace, they are making their way through what looks to be a jungle. Leela slices through the vegetation with a large knife in both episodes.

Also, if there are no jungles on Earth, why? Is it due to pollution, dehydration, deforestation? Anything?

I don't know if jungles appear in any other episodes, or if it's just a rainforest, but I just noticed this a few days ago.

Comment: The writers make it a sport to contradict themselves as much as possible (yes, intentionally!), so it's really hard to come up with definite statements about mostly anything.

Comment: Don't have enough material yet.  Noting that in S04E13, Bender used a fake jungle[Congo] disease to get out of marrying Calculon.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the Congo disease that both Bender and Calculon act out is also a dead give away.

Answer (score 1):

This continuity error can be resolved by simply assuming that a jungle has been transplanted from Mars to Earth in the eleven years between those two episodes. The Congo is also a state (two, actually), not just a jungle, so the disease mentioned in that episode need not be jungle-related.

As for the reasons behind the jungles disappearing, deforestation, global warming and nuclear winter are all mentioned as having occurred in the first Christmas episode (*Xmas Story*), which also reveals the extinction of pine trees (along with poodles, which are seen in the episode *The Mutants are Revolting*). It seems likely that one of these disasters also caused the extinction of Earth's jungles, though it's never noted which of these disasters, if any, are responsible.